# Make changes to /sys persistent between boots

Tags: linux, kernel, filesystems, configuration

I want to make `"echo 1 > /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run"` persistent between boots. I know that I can edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make `/proc` filesystem changes persist, but this doesn't seem to work for `/sys`. How would I make this change survive reboots?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most distros have some sort of an rc.local script that you could use. Check your distro as names and path may vary. Normally expect to look under /etc.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, though @camh 's [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25388/29) allowed me to google for this. `sysfs.conf` obviously doesn't exist on arch

Comment: sysfsutils is packaged in AUR, but it seems that the sysfs.conf functionality is a debian patch that has not been upstreamed.

Answer (score 22):

Debian has the package `sysfsutils` which has an init.d script that can apply settings to `/sys` based on the configuration in `/etc/sysfs.conf`.

The init script has an @debian.org author, so I suspect that this is debian-specific and may not have made it to other non-Debian distributions. However, all the logic is contained in the init script, so you could quite easily grab that package, extract the script and use it on your system.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/sysctl.conf` is read by one of your init scripts. This is somewhat distribution-dependent; on Debian, it's `/etc/init.d/procps`. Debian doesn't have anything like this for settings under `/sys` in its default installation ([there's the `sysfsutils` package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25388) if you want it though). If your distribution doesn't either, write an init script of your own.

(Note that `/etc/sysctl.conf` doesn't make `/proc/sys` persistent: if you set something in `/proc/sys`, it isn't saved in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.)

Comment: but @gilles `sysctl.conf` is for `/proc` not `/sys`

Comment: @xenoterracide Not for `/proc` but for sysctl values, which are exposed in `/proc/sys`.

Comment: either way it's still not `/sys` which is what this is about.